# Javascript to submit form within html page embedded in div

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a main page (index.html), where I have a  with an embedded html page(sample1.html) that I load from         `document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML`

In this sample1.html I have a form:

I am not sure how to use javascript included in the index.html level to submit this form.

I tried the following 3 options:
`document.forms[0].submit();
document.form1.submit();
document.form["sampleform1"].submit();`

All of them failed. My question is - how to get a handle of the  in an html page embedded in a  element? Not sure how this is structure in DOM.

thanks.

Comment: HTML page embedded in an element? Do you mean an iframe?

Comment: It's not an iframe. I loaded it like this: document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="html/form1.html" ></object>';

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

document.getElementById("sampleform1").click()

Comment: document.getElementById returns null for both name/id values. I think from index.html the elements within the embedded html doesn't get recognized.